# Is it possible to use tokens from auth0 for authentication?

Tags: java, ember.js, auth0

Is there a way to use Java with `auth0`?
I have an Ember app that get its token from [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/),
but I can't find any documentation of how to consume that token through the Java API.

I can do it by generating the token from Java API, but this is not what I want.

Here are the steps I want to have:

1. Ember app gets access token from [auth0.com](https://auth0.com/) **(not from the Java API)**
2. Send each request to Java API with the token bearer in the header
3. Java API should interpret the token and then serve the requested data if all is good

Answer (score 0):

[This quickstart](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security) shows you how to build a Java API that will look for a JWT `access_token` generated by Auth0 to validate each request made from a client.

The client (the Ember app or any other client) will request an access_token in the authorization call to Auth0, indicating the right `audience` (the identifier for your backend API). That `access_token` can then be used against the Java API. 
You can debug the token in https://jwt.io. The `aud` claim should contain the identifier of your backend API.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I've done that solution, but I get unauthorized. In auth0.com I have a client and an api. My ember app uses domain and client id for the auth0 client. Is that correct?

Comment: It is. You also need to make sure to add the `audience` parameter on the `authorize` request with your API's identifier, so that the `access_token` will be usable to call the API.